# Does the set of vectors $S =\{v_1,v_2,{0}\}$ span the real $3$-dimension?

Tags: vectors, real-numbers

Im trying to prove that a set of vectors, specifically in 3D, spans the real third dimension.
In general, i have read that if a set of vectors contains 3  non-coplanar vectors, they would span the real 3D. 
But I'm confused as to whether this applies to a set containing the zero vector as well? I cant seem to get an intuitive grasp on it.

I am thinking the zero vector is not taken into account, and if the two 3d vectors in this set are non-coplanar, it doesn't matter, because theres not three planes so will not span the real 3d.

I apologise if this is a obvious concept. 
Thank you.

Comment: $v_1,v_2,0$ are three coplanar vectors

Comment: @hagen-von-eitzen   Oh, I didn't know that 0 can also be a plane! My bad. Thanks

Comment: $0$ "is" not a plane. What I said is (according to the very definition of coplanarity): There *exists* a plane (strictly speaking: a pane passing through the origin) $P$ such that $v_1\in P$ and $v_2\in P$ and $0\in P$.

Answer (score 4):

The zero vector is dependent on the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. This means that you can write $0.v_1 + 0.v_2 = 0$. Therefore $0$ is element of the span $\{v_1,v_2\}$, so it's dependent on $v_1$ and $v_2$. The fact that it is 'perpendicular' because the standard inner product is $0$ does not hold in this case.

Therefore, $\{v_1,v_2,0\}$ does not span the 3-dimensional space, but the 2-dimensional space (if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent).

Comment: Thank a lot. Im gonna have to look into perpendicularity of this set, but i appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any set containing more than one vector that has the zero vector in it is linearly dependent, since you can multiply any of the other vectors in the set by zero to get the zero vector. Your set of three vectors would have to be linearly independent for it to span 3-space.

Comment: Thanks!, i forgot the linear independence rule would have to apply here too +1